# How to checkbox filtering in reactjs and handle state? and show the available item after the checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, filtering, array-filter

I want to make a filter system using multiple checkbox. But when i checked one checkbox it filter the state but when i unchecked it how i can get back the all data in state . Also if i select multiple checkbox then it will filter from the filtered item.

Here is my code.

```
state = {
  restaurant : [
     {name: 'La mesa', cuisine: ['italian', 'indian']},
     {name: 'Red Bull', cuisine: ['chiness', 'french']}
     {name: 'Purnima', cuisine: ['thai', 'arabic']}
  ]
  cuisine: [
    {id: 1, name: 'italian'},
    {id: 2, name: 'indian'},
    {id: 3, name: 'chiness'}
    {id: 4, name: 'french'},
    {id: 4, name: 'arabic'},
 ]
}

handleCuisineFilter = (e) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            const filter =
                this.state.restaurant.length &&
                this.state.restaurant.filter((rest) => rest.cuisine.includes(e.target.value));
            this.setState({ restaurant: filter });
        } else {
            Now when unchecked how i can get previous state???
        }
    };

render() {
  return (
<div>
   {this.state.cuisine.length && this.state.cuisine.map(
     cuisine=> (<li>
                   <input
                    id={cuisine.id}
                    type='checkbox'
                    onChange={this.handleCuisineFilter}
                    name='check'
                    value={cuisine.name}
                    />
              {cuisine.name }  {here will be count of number of restaurant}
               </li>
            ))}
     {this.state.restaurant.length && this.state.restaurant.map(rest=> <h5>rest.name</h5>)}
 </div>
```

I tried to explain best via my code . Help me please. Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this a typo `restaurants` or it should be `restaurant`? also you are trying to mutate original one with filter rather use `map` and do not mutate the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep track of `checked` state for each filter and then filter against all filters at once every time.

Here is the solution

**EDIT**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    restaurant: [
      { name: "La mesa", cuisine: ["italian", "indian"] },
      { name: "Red Bull", cuisine: ["chiness", "french"] },
      { name: "Purnima", cuisine: ["thai", "arabic"] },
    ],
    // maintain a checked state for each filter
    cuisine: [
      { id: 1, name: "italian", checked: false },
      { id: 2, name: "indian", checked: false },
      { id: 3, name: "chiness", checked: false },
      { id: 4, name: "french", checked: false },
      { id: 5, name: "arabic", checked: false },
    ],
  };

  setFilter = (cuisine, flag) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      cuisine: prevState.cuisine.map((c) =>
        // check state for the selected cuisine
        c.id === cuisine.id ? { ...c, checked: flag } : c
      ),
    }));
  };

  handleCuisineFilter = (e, cuisine) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.setFilter(cuisine, true);
    } else {
      this.setFilter(cuisine, false);
    }
  };

  filterRestaurants = (restaurant) => {
    const checkedFilters = this.state.cuisine.filter((c) => c.checked);
    const noFiltersChecked = checkedFilters.length === 0;

    if (noFiltersChecked) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // EDITED:
      const tmp = checkedFilters.reduce(
        (hasRestaurantAllTheseCuisines, nextCuisine) =>
          (hasRestaurantAllTheseCuisines =
            hasRestaurantAllTheseCuisines &&
            restaurant.cuisine.includes(nextCuisine.name)),
        true
      );

      return tmp;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.cuisine.length &&
          this.state.cuisine.map((cuisine) => (
            <li key={cuisine.id}>
              <input
                id={cuisine.id}
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={(e) => this.handleCuisineFilter(e, cuisine)}
                name="check"
                value={cuisine.name}
              />
              {cuisine.name} {/* here will be count of number of restaurant */}
            </li>
          ))}
        {/* Use .filter() with cuisine state */}
        {this.state.restaurant.length &&
          this.state.restaurant
            .filter(this.filterRestaurants)
            .map((rest) => <h5 key={rest.name}>{rest.name}</h5>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Edited the code. The only change was the filter check here

```
...
const tmp = checkedFilters.reduce(
  (hasRestaurantAllTheseCuisines, nextCuisine) =>
    (hasRestaurantAllTheseCuisines =
      hasRestaurantAllTheseCuisines &&
      restaurant.cuisine.includes(nextCuisine.name)),
  true
);
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution , It filtered the data , but not correctly, for exampple restaurant contain only one cuisine , when i check other cuisine that not available but still it shows some restaurant but that restaurant dont contain that cuisine

Comment: I mean i need something like if i choose cuisine and if its not available on any restaurant then it will show empty array of the restaurant , but your code seems return wrong data. can you check please. Thank you

Comment: Well, you did not mention this in your question... So if I understand correctly you need every restaurant on the list to have ALL the checked cuisines

Comment: Yes. for example there are 4 restaurant and one restaurant contain the cuisine "italian" , so if i checked italian cuisine then only this one restaurant will show. if restaurant cuisine contain 2 or more cuisine like [italian, indian] then if i checked both cuisine then this restaurant will visible others not , coz it has both cuisine that i selected. Can you re-write your code please. Thank you